# getFromLocation(latitude,longitude, number) function returns null for known position

Tags: android, null

I'm using a `Geocoder` to locate my location with address, postal code and country values included.

But `getFromLocation(latitude,longitude,number)` returns null, even though i use known location attributes ( Latitude: 40,645081 Longitude: 22,988892 ).

I'm testing my app on an AVD (API Level 7), using Eclipse.

Thanks in advance.

Here is a snippet of where the `getFromLocation` function is used.

```
private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location){
    String latLongString;
    TextView myLocationText;
    myLocationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myLocationText);

    String addressString = "No address found";

    if (location != null) {
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();
        latLongString = "Lat:" + lat + "\nLong:" + lng;

        //double latitude = 73.147536;
        //double longitude = 0.510638;
        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

        try {
            List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
            Log.v("TRY_BODY", "All addresses are: " + addresses);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                Log.v("IF_BODY", "All addresses are: " + addresses);
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++){
                    sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                    sb.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
                    sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
                    sb.append(address.getCountryName());
                }
                addressString = sb.toString();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    } 
    else {
        latLongString = "No location found";
    }

    myLocationText.setText("Current Position:\n"+latLongString + "\n" + addressString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very common, sometimes google server does not return any address, so that you should try it agian, it could be anything server busy, or somethimg else,
you can run this code in any thread with a loop, and if the address comes successfully, you can stop the loop and it will end the thread.

Comment: So a good idea would be to have it running on a background service ? 
And when it meets some criteria , show to user the results ?

Comment: Yup, but not service, just the thread, run it as a background thread, and keep getting location call from server, with some sleep time in thread obviously(For better performance).
Once you get the location, There is a method RunONUIThread or something, call it to update the UI Thread.

Comment: thnx a lot ;) i'll try it out !!